# how to using javascript to get data from couchdb

Tags: javascript, html, couchdb, heatmap

I have store some document in `couchdb`, and generate a view using map reduce. Every document in the view is in following structure :

```
{user_name, longitude, latitude, tweet_content}
```

Now I need to use the `api` of google map to show these point. (The heatmap) I need to get the value of longitude and latitude in the that view in `couchdb`. The google map provide the HTML code to show the heatmap,
(https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap) 
I just need the data of coordination. The problems seems like how to use Javascript to connect with `couchdb`.  I just have no idea about how to get start, and cannot find any instruction about how to write the Javascript code in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

The heatmap code you have referred to will be executed client-side in the browser.

> I just have no idea about how to get start, and cannot find any instruction about how to write the Javascript code in HTML.

The JavaScript code can be included into your HTML in several ways. Start by reading [about the HTML script tag](http://mdn.io/script).

> The problems seems like how to use Javascript to connect with couchdb.

Once your HTML content is loaded in the browser you can communicate with CouchDB via [AJAX calls](http://mdn.io/ajax)

Comment: hello, @llabball. Thank you very much for help. But I am totally new to Ajax. Would you mind to give me a general example? Say, I have a HTML document called heatmap.html, whose content is in the (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap), and I have a database called UK in couchdb, which contains attributes of latitude and longitude. How can I get the value of latitude and longitude from UK in the heatmap.html? Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you llabball. After following your suggestion, I have work it out. To help someone who also have this trouble, the following is my answer.

Comment: $.ajax({
      url: 'http://name:password@localhost:5984/yourdatabase/_design/analyse/_view/viewname',
      type: 'get',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        data.rows.forEach(function(tweet){

          taxiData.push(new google.maps.LatLng(tweet.key[0], tweet.key[1]))
          console.log(tweet.key[0]);
        });
      },
      reduce: false
    });

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'http://name:password@localhost:5984/yourdatabase/_design/analyse/_view/viewname',
      type: 'get',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        data.rows.forEach(function(tweet){

          taxiData.push(new google.maps.LatLng(tweet.key[0], tweet.key[1]))
          console.log(tweet.key[0]);
        });
      },
      reduce: false
    });
```